# Firebase Test Lab error "Unexpected error abandoning session"

Tags: firebase-test-lab

A lot of my tests fail on Firebase Test Lab.  I tend to see the following error:

```
04-28 20:54:13.686: W/Finsky(11726): [141] nao.b(6): Unexpected error abandoning session=726608967. exception=java.lang.SecurityException: Caller has no access to session 726608967
```

First of all, what component is `Finsky`?

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Finsky is the Google Play Store. There's not much info here to go on, but perhaps your app doesn't have some needed permission declared in your manifest?